# Graphics.drawString() Isn't Drawing

Tags: java, awt

I am creating a simple Mahjong game for a final project at school and seem to be having some troubles with the `drawString()` method on the Graphics/Graphics2D object. I call the `drawString` method and see nothing written to the screen.

In my scenario I have extended the `JFrame` class and overridden the `paintComponent()` method to create a custom graphical object, specifically a mahjong tile. Using polygons described in various arrays I create a faux 3D view of a tile drawing the face, right side, and bottom of the tile. These polygons are filled using `GradientPaint` objects to give the tile a better appearance. Here is what it looks like:

[image: Rendered Tile]

My `Tile` class looks like this (note: some code was omitted for brevity):

```
public class Tile extends JPanel
{
    private int _width;
    private int _height;
    private int _depth;

    /**
     * Accessor to get the center of the face of the rendered
     * mahjong tile.
     *
     * @return A point containing the center of the face of the tile.
     */
    public Point getCenter()
    {
        return new Point(_width / 2, _height / 2);
    }

    /**
     * The default constructor creates a tile that is proportionally
     * calculated to 80 pixels wide.
     */
    public Tile()
    {
        this(80);
    }

    /**
     * Given the width parameter a mahjong tile is drawn according to
     * the proportions of a size 8 mahjong tile.
     *
     * @param width The width of the tile to be rendered.
     */
    public Tile(int width)
    {
        _width = width;
        _height = (int)(width * 1.23);
        _depth = (int)((width * 0.3) / 2);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension((_width + _depth) + 1, (_height + _depth) + 1));
    }

    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        // ... setup polygon arrays ...

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        // Turn on anti-aliasing.
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // ... setup various gradients ...

        // Fill the face of the tile.
        g2d.setPaint(faceGradient);
        g2d.fillPolygon(faceXPolyPoints, faceYPolyPoints, faceXPolyPoints.length);

        // Fill the right side of the top portion of the tile.
        g2d.setPaint(ivoryRightSideGradient);
        g2d.fillPolygon(ivoryRightSideXPolyPoints, ivoryRightSideYPolyPoints, ivoryRightSideXPolyPoints.length);

        // Fill the bottom side of the top portion of the tile.
        g2d.setPaint(ivoryBottomGradient);
        g2d.fillPolygon(ivoryBottomXPolyPoints, ivoryBottomYPolyPoints, ivoryBottomXPolyPoints.length);

        // Fill the right side of the bottom portion of the tile.
        g2d.setPaint(jadeRightSideGradient);
        g2d.fillPolygon(jadeRightSideXPolyPoints, jadeRightSideYPolyPoints, jadeRightSideXPolyPoints.length);

        // Fill the bottom side of the bottom portion of the tile.
        g2d.setPaint(jadeBottomGradient);
        g2d.fillPolygon(jadeBottomXPolyPoints, jadeBottomYPolyPoints, jadeBottomXPolyPoints.length);

        // Draw the outlines for the tile.
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawPolygon(faceXPolyPoints, faceYPolyPoints, faceXPolyPoints.length);
        g2d.drawPolygon(ivoryRightSideXPolyPoints, ivoryRightSideYPolyPoints, ivoryRightSideXPolyPoints.length);
        g2d.drawPolygon(ivoryBottomXPolyPoints, ivoryBottomYPolyPoints, ivoryBottomXPolyPoints.length);
        g2d.drawPolygon(jadeBottomXPolyPoints, jadeBottomYPolyPoints, jadeBottomXPolyPoints.length);
        g2d.drawPolygon(jadeRightSideXPolyPoints, jadeRightSideYPolyPoints, jadeRightSideXPolyPoints.length);
    }
}
```

As you may know, there are many different types of mahjong tiles one being a character tile that displays various Chinese characters on the tile face. So my `Tile` class sets up the basic drawing of a tile and I create a new `CharacterTile` class that extends/inherits the `Tile` class. The code for that class follows:

```
public class CharacterTile extends Tile
{
    private Character _character;

    public CharacterTile(Character character)
    {
        super();

        _character = character;
    }

    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        String charToWrite;


        switch (_character)
        {
            case ONE:
                charToWrite = "\u4E00";
                break;
            case TWO:
                charToWrite = "\u4E8C";
                break;
            case THREE:
                charToWrite = "\u4E09";
                break;
            case FOUR:
                charToWrite = "\u56DB";
                break;
            case FIVE:
                charToWrite = "\u4E94";
                break;
            case SIX:
                charToWrite = "\u516D";
                break;
            case SEVEN:
                charToWrite = "\u4E03";
                break;
            case EIGHT:
                charToWrite = "\u516B";
                break;
            case NINE:
                charToWrite = "\u4E5D";
                break;
            case NORTH:
                charToWrite = "\u5317";
                break;
            case EAST:
                charToWrite = "\u6771";
                break;
            case WEST:
                charToWrite = "\u897F";
                break;
            case SOUTH:
                charToWrite = "\u5357";
                break;
            case RED:
                charToWrite = "\u4E2D";
                break;
            case GREEN:
                charToWrite = "\u767C";
                break;
            case WAN:
                charToWrite = "\u842C";
                break;
            default:
                charToWrite = "?";
                break;
        }

        g2d.drawString(charToWrite, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

As you can see the default constructor for the `CharacterTile` class accepts an `enum` indicating the desired face value. Inside the overridden `paintComponent` I have a switch statement that sets the appropriate character to write and then I call the `g2d.drawString()` method to write the character in the upper left corner. The problem? It doesn't write anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you selected a font that has those Chinese characters in it? (Note: I know nothing about AWT so it's possible that this question is fundamentally misconceived.) What happens if you use plain ol' ASCII characters as the `charToWrite` values?

Comment: Yes, first try to write "normal" characters like "A".

Comment: +1 Great question from a student.

Comment: Yep, I've tried writing normal latin characters with the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
g2d.drawString(charToWrite, 0, 0);
```

You need to specify the bottom/left coordinate when you draw a string. Try something like:

```
g2d.drawString(charToWrite, 0, 10);
```

Also, you need to make sure the component has a valid size. By default the size is (0, 0), which means there is nothing to paint. This is generally done by specifying a preferred size and then let the layout manager set the size.

Comment: It was simply out of sight. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String fontString = "MS Gothic";
Font font = new Font(fontString, Font.PLAIN, 24);
g2d.setFont(font);
```

before `drawString()`

try Apple Gothic if you are on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

With what `color` are you calling `g2d.drawString()`?

For example:

```
    //add this line before next
    g2d.setBackground(Color.BLACK); //or 'g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);'
    g2d.drawString(charToWrite, 0, 0);
```

Are you sure, that current font has the symbols you are trying to paint? - Change the font.

Answer (score 0):

I am glad I am not the only one having this issue for class.  I haven't tested this yet but according to this site http://www.herongyang.com/Swing/JFrame-Draw-Chinese-Character-on-Frame.html  this font should work for creating the font that you need to create the characters.

```
g2d.setFont(new Font("SimSun",Font.PLAIN, 12));
g2d.drawString(charToWrite, 0, 0);
```

Comment: You don't even need to worry about some obscure font. I am using Arial and things are working just great.

Comment: I ended up getting it working with the Arial Unicode MS font.
String fontString = "Arial Unicode MS";  Thanks for the post though.  This helped me out a lot.